# Remote working in Netherlands with Residence Permit while wife is in University

Tags: usa, visa, resident-permit, student-visa, netherlands

My wife recently acquired a student visa through the University of Amsterdam. I'm working remotely for a US-based company. We're both US citizens. Our original plan was for me to get a residence permit through her student visa and then work remotely in Amsterdam while she's in school. However it isn't clear if that is allowed.

Is there a way for me to have the residence permit through her visa and still pay taxes to the Netherlands without acquiring a work visa since my employer isn't Dutch? Or do I not need to pay taxes to Netherlands? My employer doesn't seem to be able to get me a work visa independently so I don't know what my options are for working and living in Amsterdam while my wife is in school.

Comment: This https://www.bnctax.com/blog/how-can-i-work-for-my-u-s-employer-while-im-living-in-the-netherlands/ might be useful reading